# Find a minimum value of $\frac{f^{1000}(0)}{f^{999}(0)}$

Tags: calculus

The task: let $\mathbb A$ be a set of infinitely differentiable functions $f:(-1,1)\to R$, such that for every $n \in N$ following relation holds: $f(\frac 1n)=\frac{3n^2}{(5n+1)^2}$. Find minimum value of $\frac{f^{1000}(0)}{f^{999}(0)}$ on $\mathbb A$.

My solution is:

Since for every $n \in N$ $f(\frac 1n)=\frac{3n^2}{(5n+1)^2}$, then m-th derivative at point $\frac 1n$ is $f^m(\frac 1n)=\frac{5^{m-2}m!(-10n+m-1)3}{(5n+1)^{m+2}}$, and given that $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac 1n)$ we have following
$$\frac{f^{1000}(0)}{f^{999}(0)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f^{1000}(\frac 1n)}{f^{999}(\frac 1n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5^{998}3(-10n+999)1000!}{(5n+1)^{1002}}}{\frac{-5^{997}3(-10n+998)999!}{(5n+1)^{1001}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-5(-10n+999)1000}{5(5n+1)(-10n+998)}=0$$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Can you please detail your second equality? (btw, try to find a more informative title)

Comment: What does $f^n$ mean here? It it is $f \times \cdots \times f$, you may simplify the fraction $f^{1000}(0)/f^{999}(0)$.

Comment: here $f^n$ means nth derivative, i calculated it, but did not prove the general formula i used is correct, in fact my question is, whether my approach is correct

Comment: Try to edit your post to add the details of what you did.

Comment: If you only know the value of the function $f(x)$ at $x=1$, $x=1/2$, $x=1/3$ et cetera, you can't say anything about the derivative $f'(1/2)$. The function can do pretty much anything in between the points on the sequence. Surely a better starting point is that $f(x)$ agrees with  $g(x)=3/(5+x)^2$ at all the points $x=1/n, n$ a positive integer.

Comment: It's really too bad we don't know that $f$ is analytic. For then [the Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) would uniquely identify $f(x)=3/(5+x)^2$ :-) I guess the point of the exercise is to study exactly the difference

Comment: In view of the solution, shouldn't we simplify the question? (i.e. just take one function $f$, and ask for the value instead of the min)

Comment: To make the problem in your attempt concrete. You are given that $f(1)=1/12$. Yet you somehow deduce from this alone all the derivatives of $f$ at $1$. Basically any attempt to start differentiating $3n/(5n+1)^2$ with respect to $n$ is misguided. Here $n$ is a positive integer, not a continuous variable.

Comment: I don't think so @AnneBauval. I think that asking for a minimum is a red herring of sorts, deliberately misguiding solvers.

Comment: Oh i got it, thank you for answers and explanations, Jyrki Lahtonen and Anne Bauval

Answer (score 3):

The function
$$g(x)=\frac3{(5+x)^2}$$
shares the values with the given function $f(x)$ at the sequence of points $x=1/n$, $n$ a positive integer. This suggests that we should consider the difference
$$\phi(x)=g(x)-f(x).$$

We know that $\phi\in C^\infty(((-1,1))$ and $\phi(1/n)=0$ for all positive integers $n$.

**Claim.** For all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, we have $D^k\phi(0)=0$.

**Proof.** Assume contrariwise that some derivative $\phi$ does not vanish at $x=0$. Let $m$ be the smallest non-negative integer such $D^m\phi(0)=A\neq0$.
By continuity of $D^m\phi(x)$ there exists an interval $I=[-\delta,\delta],\delta>0$ such that $|D^m\phi(x)|\ge|A|/2$ for all $x\in I$.

The degree $m-1$ Taylor polynomial of $\phi$ at zero vanishes by minimality of $m$. So by [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) for all $x\in I$ we have
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{\phi^{(m)}(\xi)}{m!}x^m,
$$
where $\xi$ lies between $0$ and $x$. By our earlier consideration we know that
$|\phi^{(m)}(\xi)|\ge |A|/2$. It follows that for all $x\in I$ we have
$$
|\phi(x)|\ge \frac{|A||x|^m}{2 m!}.
$$
In particular, $\phi(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in I, x\neq0$. This is a contradiction.

So it follows that for all $f\in C^\infty((-1,1))$ with the prescribed values at the points $1/n, n=1,2,\ldots$, we have
$$
\frac{f^{(1000)}(0)}{f^{(999)}(0)}=\frac{g^{(1000)}(0)}{g^{(999)}(0)}.
$$
Leaving the rest to you.

Comment: I could not find a duplicate, but surely the argument of the claim is standard, and probably has appeared here earlier. It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure it out, but I do relatively little real analysis :-)

Answer (score 1):

For $\phi$ like in Jyrki's answer, using Rolle's theorem, you can easily prove by induction that for any $k\in\Bbb N,$ $\phi^{(k)}$ admits a decreasing sequence of zeros which converges to $0.$

Therefore, $$\forall k\in\Bbb N\quad\phi^{(k)}(0)=0.$$

Comment: Simpler than Taylor :-)